# How can I loop through combinations of values with `pytest.raises`, and find out which combination failed?

Tags: pytest

I use `pytest.raises` for tuples of values in an array:

```py
import pytest


def test_division():
    pairs = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
    for a, b in pairs:
        with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
            a / b
```

It fails as expected when one of the tuples does not cause the error.
But it does not tell me which tuple was the problem:

```
================================================ FAILURES ================================================
_____________________________________________ test_division ______________________________________________

    def test_division():
        pairs = [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
        for a, b in pairs:
            with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
>               a / b
E               Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>

proj/divide_test.py:8: Failed
======================================== short test summary info =========================================
FAILED proj/divide_test.py::test_division - Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
====================================== 1 failed, 3 passed in 0.04s =======================================
```

In this case I would like to be told that the pair `(0, 1)` was the problem.
Is there a way to make that information accessible?

Comment: You could use parametrization for the different tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the values inside the test, use parametrization:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("pair", ((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)), ids=str)
def test_division(pair):
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        pair[0] / pair[1]
```

This handles each value as a separate test, and you get:

```
collecting ... collected 3 items

div_by_zero.py::test_division[(1, 0)] PASSED                             [ 33%]
div_by_zero.py::test_division[(0, 1)] FAILED                             [ 66%]
div_by_zero.py:2 (test_division[(0, 1)])
pair = (0, 1)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("pair", ((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)), ids=str)
    def test_division(pair):
        with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
>           pair[0] / pair[1]
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>

div_by_zero.py:6: Failed

div_by_zero.py::test_division[(0, 0)] PASSED                             [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
...
div_by_zero.py:6: Failed
========================= 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.08s =========================
```

EDIT: added `ids=str` to make the output better readable as suggested by @hoefling

Comment: I'd enhance by passing the `ids` to see the exact pair instead of `pairX`, e.g. `@pytest.mark.parametrize("pair", ((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)), ids=str)`

Comment: @hoefling Thanks - good point! I updated the answer accordingly.